# Async series in node js ? page is first rendered before the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have my code below when uses async series first I query for the list of vehicle and then using the VIN from the vehicle result i used it to query for the list of files and chucks but I cant get the locals.data.images_gallery because it renders the page before getting the locals.data.images_gallery result and that is the reason I cannot pass the data to the view( the html ). There is no problem when it comes to locals.data.vehicle result I can render the data to the view , the problem is on locals.data.images_gallery is it late rendered.

As you can see on the code the console log 2 is being rendered first before the console log 1 .

As you can see with the screenshot below , when the script is called the console log 2 is first called with the length is 0 before the log 1 which has the lenght of 13 , that is why when the page is rendered it has empty data.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYmBM.jpg

What is the problem with this style ? any solution ? like is it because of the async call?

I just want to get the locals.data.images_gallery. but when the script is rendered its empty. because locals.data.images_gallery.length is rendered late

## Code

```
view.on('init', function (next) {

    async.series([

        function (next) {
            keystone.list('Vehicle').model.findOne()
                .where('state', 'published')
                .where('VIN', "5FNYF28677B037628")
                .exec(function (err, vehicle) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Error finding current user Vehicles', err);
                    }
                    if (vehicle) {
                        locals.data.vehicle = vehicle;
                    }
                    return next(err);
                });

        },

        function (next) {

            var docs_ids = []

            MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, client) {

                if (err) {
                    return res.render('index',
                        {
                            title: 'Uploaded Error',
                            message: 'MongoClient Connection error', error: err.errMsg
                        });
                }

                const db = client.db(dbName);
                const collection = db.collection('fs.files');
                const collectionChunks = db.collection('fs.chunks');

                collection.find({ metadata: locals.data.vehicle.VIN }).toArray(function (err, docs) {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.render('index', {
                            title: 'File error',
                            message: 'Error finding file',
                            error: err.errMsg
                        });
                    }
                    if (!docs || docs.length === 0) {
                        return res.render('index', {
                            title: 'Download Error',
                            message: 'No file found'
                        });
                    } else {

                        for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
                            docs_ids.push(docs[i]._id)
                        }

                        collectionChunks.find({ files_id: { $in: docs_ids } })
                            .sort({ n: 1 }).toArray(function (err, chunks) {
                                if (err) {
                                    return res.render('index', {
                                        title: 'Download Error',
                                        message: 'Error retrieving chunks',
                                        error: err.errmsg
                                    });
                                }
                                if (!chunks || chunks.length === 0) {
                                    return res.render('index', {
                                        title: 'Download Error',
                                        message: 'No data found'
                                    });
                                }

                                let fileData = [];

                                for (let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
                                    locals.data.images_gallery.push('data:' + docs[0].contentType + ';base64,'
                                        + chunks[i].data.toString('base64'));
                                }


                                console.log("LOG 1 " , locals.data.images_gallery.length)
                                return next();
                            });

                            
                    }


                })


            })
        },

    ], function (err) {

        if (err) {
            locals.data.err = err
        }
        locals.data.results = locals.data
        next();
    })

    console.log("LOG 2" , locals.data.images_gallery.length)
```

Comment: step 1: simplify this code for demonstration purposes by forming an [mcve]. The benefit of doing so is that you almost always discover what the problem is by running through that exercise, but in the rare case you don't, you now have a far better and more laser-focussed bit of code to show.

Comment: The only problem with the code sir is locals.data.images_gallery is rendered late